# handling brackets and parentheses better in vimmode in atom

Tags: vim, atom-editor

I love VIM and so I also love the VIMmode in Atom. I use it everyday when I program. But I always thought that handling brackets is a mess in VIMmode. When I insert a '(', Atom autocompletes it with an ')'. But when I want to write something behind the ')', I have to escape, press 'l' to go left and press 'a' again to go back into insert mode. Isn't there a shorter way to do that?
Thank you for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: Did you try typing the closing character?

Comment: Oh yeah, this is a bit faster. Thanks:)

Comment: But isn't there an even faster shortcut, which sets the cursor right behind the bracket?

Comment: Hmm… did you mean "behind" or "between"?

Comment: I mean, that I write something in between the brackets and press then a shortcut, which sets me behind the bracket.

Comment: Again, that shortcut is `)` (or `}`, or `]`, or `"`, or `'`, depending on the opening character).